# Effective Nullstellensatz and bounds on the nilpotency index of reduced ideal together with linear forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$
and let $I\subset K[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$ be an ideal generated by
(homogeneous) polynomials of degree $d$. Assume that $I$ is reduced,
that is, its nilpotency index (aka the Noether exponent; the smallest
integer $e$ such that $(\sqrt{I})^{e}\subseteq I$) is $1$. Let
$f_{1},\dots, f_{k}\in K[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]$ be linear homogeneous
polynomials.

By results of Kollár (Sharp effective Nullstellensatz), and later
improvements by Jelonek (On the effective Nullstellensatz) it is possible
to bound the nilpotency index of $(I,f_{1},\dots,f_{k})$ by $d^{n}$. I
am wondering if the knowledge that the nilpotency index of $I$ is
$1$ can be used to improve this without knowing anything else about $I$:

> Is there a bound on the nilpotency index of the ideal
>   $(I,f_{1},\dots,f_{k})$ which is better than $d^n$? Does it help if we know that the ideal
>   defines an affine group scheme, that is, if
>   $K[x_{1},\dots,x_{n}]/(I,f_{1},\dots,f_{k})$ is a Hopf algebra?

Even if we only have a bound similar to $d^{n}$ in general, I am interested
in bounding the possible prime divisors of the nilpotency index of
$(I,f_{1},\dots,f_{k})$. We certainly need at least the prime divisors
of $d$ in general, but are these enough?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: @AIM_BLB: No, I didn't.

Comment: Alright, I'll follow this post just in-case then.